# Php Imap fetching emails

Tags: php, imap

I have been trying to fetch email body with [imap_fetchbody($stream, $msgno, $option)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php)
but didn't success quite well.

Then I tried using [imap_fetchstructure($stream, $msgno)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) and decode each types manually with their own subtypes like:-

```
1. Alternative
2. Related
3. Mixed
```

For the first two I can decode with something like this

```
**1. Alternative**

if ($structure->subtype == 'ALTERNATIVE') {
    if (isset($structure->parts)) {
        $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 2);
        if ($body2 == null) {
            $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1);
        }
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($body2);
    }
}

**2. Related**

if ($structure->subtype == 'RELATED') {
    if (isset($structure->parts)) {
        $parts = $structure->parts;
        $i = 0;
        $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1.2);
        if ($body2 == null) {
            $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1);
        }
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($body2);
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if ($parts[$i]) {
            }
            $i++;
            if (isset($parts[$i])) {
                if ($parts[$i]->ifid == 1) {
                    $id = $parts[$i]->id;
                    $imageid = substr($id, 1, -1);
                    $imageid = "cid:" . $imageid;
                    if ($parts[$i]->ifdparameters == 1) {
                        foreach ($parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                            if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                                $filename = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ($parts[$i]->ifparameters == 1) {
                        foreach ($parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                            if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                                $name = $object->value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $body = str_replace($imageid, $filename, $body);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when it comes to mixed either I don't know or what am I suppose to do or where am I making mistake.

```
**3. mixed**

if ($structure->subtype == 'MIXED') {
    if (isset($structure->parts)) {
        $parts = $structure->parts;
            // subtype = ALTERNATIVE
            if ($parts[0]->subtype == 'ALTERNATIVE') {
                if (isset($structure->parts)) {                                                                          
                    $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1.2);
                    if ($body2 == null) {
                        $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1);
                    }
                    $body = quoted_printable_decode($body2);
                }
            }
            // subtype = RELATED
            if ($parts[0]->subtype == 'RELATED') {
                if (isset($parts[0]->parts)) {
                    $parts = $parts[0]->parts;
                    $i = 0;
                    $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1.1);
                    if ($body2 == null) {
                        $body2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1);
                    }
                    $body = quoted_printable_decode($body2);
                    $name = "";
                    foreach ($parts as $part) {
                        if ($parts[0]) {
                        }
                        $i++;
                        if (isset($parts[$i])) {
                            if ($parts[$i]->ifid == 1) {
                                $id = $parts[$i]->id;
                                $imageid = substr($id, 1, -1);
                                $imageid = "cid:" . $imageid;
                                if ($parts[$i]->ifdparameters == 1) {
                                    foreach ($parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                                        if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                                            $filename = $object->value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($parts[$i]->ifparameters == 1) {
                                    foreach ($parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                                        if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {                                                                                  
                                             $name = $object->value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            $body = str_replace($imageid, $name, $body);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I get an answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the subtype PLAIN. Also you have to decode it too

```
if ($parts[0]->subtype == 'PLAIN') {
            if (isset($structure->parts)) {                                        
                    $message2 = imap_fetchbody($stream, $email_id, 1);
                    $message = quoted_printable_decode(base64_decode($message2));
            }
    }
```